# Cisco router compatible with optical fiber

Tags: cisco, router, fiber

I have a 887VA Cisco router (just to let you know the kind of router I'm already familiar with, its size and capabilities...).

Now, I need **another** Cisco router (resembling the 887VA) in which I can directly plug the **fiber-optic** connector for my Internet operator without any box or other intermediary equipment.

I read that it is possible, can you confirm this?

**EDIT:** Someone told me that he used an ONT + a Billion Bipac 7800DXL using its EWAN port...

Thank you.

Comment: Have you any specification from your ISP of what they give you?  Specifically connector details and so on.

Comment: The answer is yes, but remember that product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic on SE sites, except [softwarerecs.se] and [hardwarerecs.se].

Comment: I understand but I'm desperate. I just would like to know if it exists, what it looks like. I'm really not familiar with optic-fiber. I'm totally new to it. Maybe I should post my question on "Hardware Recommendations" then...

Comment: My ISP is hard to talk to :( (like any other I guess) especially for technical advice and it is going to install a box (I guess) without really taking my requirements into consideration. At least experience shows that.

Comment: There are no tags "optical" or "optic" or "fiber" on "Hardware Recommendations"...

Comment: Sounds like someone asking how to remove their AT&T Uverse gateway -- can't be done, btw. You need to know what that optical line is, first. Is it ethernet, PON, SONET, ??? Then you'll need to know what wavelength and power level it is. A lot can be learned by looking at the ISP's gear.

Comment: I don't understand the first sentence of your answer. The ISP is Orange. How can I look at the ISP's gear? Thanks.

Comment: Your edit to remove the off-topic request for a recommendation is now off-topic because it is a consumer-grade device. You really should read what is or is not on-topic here in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2):

If you've got experience of the 880-series and no experience of fibre, **consider looking at the 890 series as a starting point**.  It's pretty similar to the 880 series, but they have [SFP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_form-factor_pluggable_transceiver) ("small form-factor pluggable") interfaces, which is one of the most common optical interface kinds.  You choose the SFP depending on what the other end tells you.  **There are many other kinds of fibre connectors** but this is very common, and you can see from the way Cisco positions this product it's quite possibly suitable for your kind of situation.

EDIT: additionally it needs pointing out that even if the fibre is suitable, there might be protocol and demarcation issues.

**The question to ask is: can I plug it straight into the SFP port of my router?  If so, what connector type and speed?**  One client's ISP gave the answers "certainly" and "LC" and "SX" (short wavelength, 850 nm), you just buy those and it's hardly more tricky than copper ethernet patch cables.  If you're lucky, yours will be like this.

But at other clients' sites it's more complex.  I'm looking at one installation where the fibre arrives into a small ZTE termination unit ONT and then to client router over copper patch.  Another has fibre into a large Fujitsu rackmount termination (over SFP), then copper to ISP router and then copper to client router.  In both those cases it would not have been consistent with the ISP to plug the fibre into the client router.

I'm afraid what's going to suit you is all in the detail, but I hope this helps a little.

Comment: So hum, what piece of information do I have to ask the ISP (Orange, France)? The salespersons from Orange sell Liveboxes... they are not ready to hear from someone who doesn't want a Livebox. They just told me today that the Livebox is compulsory for the fiber. I don't believe it but I'm not sure. I would like one traditional copper line for the fax. Another one for the phone and the fiber only for the Internet. Does it look stupid?

Comment: As far as I understand it, those units have SFP sockets and the ISP sometimes delivers on fibre, and whether you can get rid of the ONT depends on many details.  My recommendation is read on a specialist forum for this kind of thing, such as https://lafibre.info/remplacer-livebox/ and https://gonzague.me/remplacer-sa-livebox-fibre-orange-par-un-routeur-linux